# Как избежать множественного перечисления IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq

Есть метод, возвращающий последовательность, состоящую из пар соседних элементов. Например, по последовательности {1,2,3} метод должен вернуть две пары: (1,2) и (2,3).

Решение, которое сразу пришло в голову:

```
return items 
    .Take(items.Count() - 1) 
    .Zip(items.Skip(1), Tuple.Create);
```

Но в данном случае IEnumerable перечисляется больше одного раза. Как можно решить задачу без нескольких перечислений (сохранив метод ленивым)?

Comment: в `F#` такой метод есть =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так. Объявим метод расширения, который выдаёт последовательные пары:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<R> Pairwise<T, R>(
            this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, T, R> selector)
    {
        using (var it = sequence.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!it.MoveNext())
                yield break;
            T prev = it.Current;
            while (it.MoveNext())
                yield return selector(prev, prev = it.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

И пользуемся:

```
return items.Pairwise(Tuple.Create);
```

Answer (score 3):

Как насчет отдельной функции?

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> GetItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
        var prev = default(T);
        var firstVisited = false;
        foreach(var item in source)
        {
            if (firstVisited)
            {
                yield return Tuple.Create(prev, item);
            }
            else
            {
                firstVisited = true;                
            }           
            prev = item;
        }
}
```