# Разбить текст по 2 и 1 слову в массив

Tags: c#

Как разбивать текст ещё и по 2 слова в массив исключая разнообразные символы, а не только по 1 ?

```
private void Algoritm()
{
    string str = "Строка в C# — это массив знаков, объявленный с помощью ключевого слова string. Строковый литерал объявляется с помощью кавычек";
    string[] items = str.Split(' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', '+', '-', '\n');

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        textBox.AppendText(items[i] + Environment.NewLine);
    }

}// Алгоритм
```

- Строка в
- в C#
- и т.д...

Comment: А сами написать не? Идти по массиву с шагом 2, брать  предыдущий и текущий и вставлять в новый массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, воспользоваться функцией `Pairwise` [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/755769/10105).

С этой функцией ваш код практически делает то, что надо. Нужно лишь добавить `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
string str = "Строка в C# — это массив знаков, объявленный с помощью ключевого слова string."
              + "Строковый литерал объявляется с помощью кавычек";
string[] items = str.Split(new[] {' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', '+', '-', '—', '\n' },
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var combined in items.Pairwise((l, r) => $"{l} {r}"))
    Console.WriteLine(combined);
```

Я добавил в список исключаемых символов тире.